# Vue Quasar q-table for multiples arrays in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

I'm currently trying to show a table with a dynamic number of columns depending on the response from the API.

Here is an example of API response I have (The number of elements in the dataExportColumnsTagList can vary from 1 to many ... For this example I put 3 elements):

```
allData:[
{
  "id": 167831,
  "tag": "House1",
  "timestamp": "2020-12-17T00:00:00",
  "dataExportColumnsTagList": [
    {
      "element_tag": "PROD_ELEMENT",
      "display_unit_tag": "Gram",
      "value": 23,
      "index": 1
    },
    {
      "element_tag": "PROD_A",
      "display_unit_tag": "Day",
      "value": 5,
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "element_tag": "PROD_T",
      "display_unit_tag": "Degree Celsius",
      "value": 25,
      "index": 0
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 167834,
  "tag": "House1",
  "timestamp": "2020-12-17T03:10:19",
  "dataExportColumnsTagList": [
    {
      "element_tag": "PROD_ELEMENT",
      "display_unit_tag": "Gram",
      "value": 22,
      "index": 1
    },
    {
      "element_tag": "PROD_A",
      "display_unit_tag": "Day",
      "value": 5,
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "element_tag": "PROD_T",
      "display_unit_tag": "Degree Celsius",
      "value": 24,
      "index": 0
    }
  ]
}
]
```

I want the table to be formatted as this :

| timestamp | tag | PROD_ELEMENT (Gram) | Index | PROD_A (Day) | Index | PROD_T (D Celsius) | Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-17 00:00:00 | House1 | 23 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 25 | 0 |
| 2020-12-17 03:10:19 | House1 | 22 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 24 | 0 |

I'm not able to iterate over the element that are repeating (dataExportColumnsTagList)...

Here is my code for now :

```
<template>
  <q-table style="margin-top: 16px"
    class="q-mb-sm q-ml-sm"
    :data="allData"
    :columns="columns"
    :pagination.sync="pagination"
    row-key="id"
  >
    <template v-slot:body="props">
      <q-tr :props="props">
        <q-td key="timestamp" :props="props">
            {{ props.row.timestamp.replace('T', ' ') }}
        </q-td>
        <q-td key="datasite_tag" :props="props">
          {{ props.row.datasite_tag }}
        </q-td>

        <q-td :props="props" v-for="dataExportColumnst in allData[id].dataExportColumnsTagList" :key="dataExportColumnst.datapoint_descriptor_tag">
          {{ dataExportColumnst.value }}
        </q-td>
        <q-td key="index" :props="props">
            {{ props.row.index }}
        </q-td>
      </q-tr>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:top-right>
      <q-btn
        color="primary"
        icon-right="archive"
        label="Export to csv"
        no-caps
        @click="exportTable"
      />
    </template>
  </q-table>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer here was bothering me, so here's the answer you were looking for.

I did need to modify the columns, since I didn't know how yours is set up.

Note:
Quasar changed `data` property to `rows` and `pagination.sync` was changed to `v-model:pagination` in Vue 3. [Link](https://quasar.dev/start/upgrade-guide#qtable)

```
<template>
    <q-table 
        style="margin-top: 16px"
        class="q-mb-sm q-ml-sm"
        :data="allData"
        :columns="columns"
        :pagination.sync="pagination"
        row-key="id"
    >
        <template v-slot:body="props">
            <q-tr :props="props">
                <q-td key="timestamp" :props="props">
                    {{ props.row.timestamp.replace('T', ' ') }}
                </q-td>
                <q-td key="tag" :props="props">
                    {{ props.row.tag }}
                </q-td>
                

                <template v-for="row in props.row.dataExportColumnsTagList">
                    <q-td :props="props" :key="row.element_tag">
                        {{ row.value }}
                    </q-td>
                    <q-td :key="`${row.element_tag}_INDEX`" :props="props">
                        {{ row.index }}
                    </q-td>
                </template>
            </q-tr>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:top-right>
            <q-btn
                color="primary"
                icon-right="archive"
                label="Export to csv"
                no-caps
                @click="exportTable"
             />
        </template>
    </q-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            columns: [
                {
                    label: 'timestamp',
                    name: 'timestamp',
                    field: 'timestamp',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    label: 'tag',
                    name: 'tag',
                    field: 'tag',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    label: 'PROD_ELEMENT (gram)',
                    name: 'PROD_ELEMENT',
                    field: 'PROD_ELEMENT',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    label: 'PROD_ELEMENT_INDEX',
                    name: 'PROD_ELEMENT_INDEX',
                    field: 'PROD_ELEMENT_INDEX',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    label: 'PROD_A (Day)',
                    name: 'PROD_A',
                    field: 'PROD_A',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    label: 'PROD_A Index',
                    name: 'PROD_A_INDEX',
                    field: 'PROD_A_INDEX',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    label: 'PROD_T (D Celsius)',
                    name: 'PROD_T',
                    field: 'PROD_T',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    label: 'PROD_T Index',
                    name: 'PROD_T_INDEX',
                    field: 'PROD_T_INDEX',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: true,
                },
            ],
            allData: [
                {
                    id: 167831,
                    tag: 'House1',
                    timestamp: '2020-12-17T00:00:00',
                    dataExportColumnsTagList: [
                        {
                            element_tag: 'PROD_ELEMENT',
                            display_unit_tag: 'Gram',
                            value: 23,
                            index: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            element_tag: 'PROD_A',
                            display_unit_tag: 'Day',
                            value: 5,
                            index: 0,
                        },
                        {
                            element_tag: 'PROD_T',
                            display_unit_tag: 'Degree Celsius',
                            value: 25,
                            index: 0,
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: 167834,
                    tag: 'House1',
                    timestamp: '2020-12-17T03:10:19',
                    dataExportColumnsTagList: [
                        {
                            element_tag: 'PROD_ELEMENT',
                            display_unit_tag: 'Gram',
                            value: 22,
                            index: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            element_tag: 'PROD_A',
                            display_unit_tag: 'Day',
                            value: 5,
                            index: 0,
                        },
                        {
                            element_tag: 'PROD_T',
                            display_unit_tag: 'Degree Celsius',
                            value: 24,
                            index: 0,
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        };
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not exactly how I'll do it, but it did push me in the right direction!

Comment: @LolCat Didn't feel right leaving you with conforming data, I think the latest edit is more along the lines :)

Comment: Thank your for the edit! I hope this answer will help other people too.